# How to combine Naive Bayes and Logistic Regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, natural-language, naive-bayes

I am working on an NLP binary classification problem. I trained a model with linear regression and a naive Bayes classifier. I found out that I am getting a good recall value in linear regression but not that good precision but this is opposite in Naive Bayes classifier. I wanted to if there is a way to combine these two models and I wanted to understand why this is happening?

Comment: Different models will be better at different things. Have you tried plotting the predicted class probabilities? Is what you say true for all thresholds of class assignment? If you can provide some more detail someone can answer your question.